# How to select single item from listview and display resulted name of row in another activity

Tags: android, listview

I got problem when trying to get  checked item from `listView`  through predefined `xml` layout `simple_list_item_single_choice` and select item then set text  of a `TextView`  that is in another activity.
 This is my `showMyUI` method that call from `MainActivity` on click of `TextView`

```
dateRange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Range clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
DateRangeClass day=new DateRangeClass(MainActivity.this,dayRangeSelected);
day.showMyUI();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.left_to_right);
        }
    });
```

And my DateRangeClass is

```
package tutorial.projecttwofilter;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class DateRangeClass {
Context context;
LinearLayout backButton;
ListView rangeList;
TextView rangeText;
String[] dateRangeData= new String[]{"Next 7 Days", "Next 14 Days", "Next 30 Days"};

  public DateRangeClass(Context context,TextView rangeText) {
    this.context = context;
      this.rangeText=rangeText;
}

 public  void  showMyUI(){
    ((Activity)context).setContentView(R.layout.daterange);
     backButton= (LinearLayout) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.backButton);
     backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override


           public void onClick(View v) {
               ((Activity) context).finish();
               ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);


           }
       });


         rangeList= (ListView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.dateRangeList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, dateRangeData);

         rangeList.setAdapter(adapter);


        rangeList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                rangeList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                if(rangeList.isItemChecked(position))
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Checked item is"+rangeList.getCheckedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  rangeText.setText("You new Change "+rangeList.getCheckedItemPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Nothing selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            });

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create DateRangeClass as an activity not as normal class and pass the information using bundle. As i can see you are passing textview instead of that you can pass text as string and can show in second activity.

To transfer data

```
String textToBesend  = "Text from textview";

Intent i = new Intent(this, DateRangeActivity.class);
i.putExtra("text", textToBesend);
startActivity(i);
```

and to recieve data in DateRangeActivity write this in oncreate method.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String textPassedFromFirstActivity = intent.getExtras().getString("text");
```

You can refer below tutorial for your purpose hope it helps.
[passing data to activity from listview](http://javatechig.com/android/pass-a-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Comment: Thank you ,in my project only single activity that is Main Activity  all other such DateRangeClass is class not an activity.and it is possible to use as class not an activity.

Comment: if you want ui related operation then you have use any of these activity, fragment or alertdialouge. It not possible with normal java class. As android widget can not be bind to them.

Comment: Thanks CodingRat for reply.

Comment: if my answer helped you then please accept and upvote so it can help other also :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not started your activity.

Use startActivity and putIntent method on button click and in your second activity use getIntent method to display the text.

Comment: Thank you , but DateRangeClass is not a activity it is a class.